# Google Swiffy Extension convert AS2 Flash animation to HTML5 animation for DoubleClick Studio

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy, double-click-advertising

First of all, sorry for my poor english.
Recently, i had try Google Swiffy extension to convert my Flash AS2 animation to HTML5 animation, however the clickTAG are not recgonize in DoubleClick studio.

I refer to the post [DoubleClick Studio ClickTag after using Swiffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022085/doubleclick-studio-clicktag-after-using-swiffy) but I encounter other 2 issue. Once i clink on the HTML5 animation, it open 2 tab, i believe it was clickTAG url and DoubleClick Studio Exit button. Also there is customised replay button on my AS2 flash animation but i think i was overlay by the DoubleClick Studio Exit button and it not clickable.

I had come out some few idea but i not sure how to execute yet.

1. Customise the shape of the DoubleClick Studio Exit button so that i won't overlay on the replay button. I'm not sure how it can be done by css or other method.
2. Create a function that able communicate between clickTag and D oubleClick Studio Exit button so that once the exit event changed in Double-click studio will reflect into clickTAG too. Im not expertise of  javascript programming and i not sure how it can be done.
3. Create another layer of replay button on of HTML5 animation once animation ended. It seem related with programming too.

I heard from my Media Buyer that they can direct convert the flash into HTML5 with working clickTAG via DoubleClick, and i was wonder how DoubleClick able to convert correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

flash clicktag must not installed

create a href  before  swiffycontainer and close it after swiffycontainer

so put this line :

like this one :

```
<a href=”” id=”clickArea” target=”_blank”>
<div id=”swiffycontainer” style=”width: 300px; height: 250px”>
</div>
</a>



now before closing the body put this script .

<script>
var clickTAG;
function px_getClickTAG() {
try {
var strsrch = window.location.search;
if (typeof(strsrch.length) != ‘undefined’) {if
(strsrch.length > 1) {clickTAG =
strsrch.split(“clickTAG=”)[1];}}
} catch (e) {console.log(e)}
}
px_getClickTAG();
var clickArea = document.getElementById(“clickArea”);
clickArea.href = clickTAG;
</script>
```

if you still do not understand . see the photo
http://graphicscoder.org/?page_id=326

Comment: Hi Salma, thanks for sharing. Do you have any advise if my swf do have replay button? By using the method above was overlayed the replay button.