# Google DCM on swiffy converted HTML5, double window open error

Tags: html, banner, google-swiffy, double-click-advertising

I have converted my .swf to HTML5 using Google Swiffy. But recently one Media Agency says the banners had a problem opening 2 new tabs instead of just one.

This is the code I always used and its having the double tab, the agency says it redirects to a route on the device ex: file:///Users/folder/folder/UNDEFINED and the other one to the DCM server.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=250">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var clickTag = "http://www.google.com"; </script>
        <title>GOOGLE DCM</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v8.0/runtime.js"></script>

        <script>
          swiffyobject = { blablabla swiffy code};
        </script>
    <style>html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}</style>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
     <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)" style="width:300px; height:250px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index:999;">
    <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 300px; height: 250px; border:1px solid black;  box-sizing: border-box; ">
    </div>
     </a>

    <script>
      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {});

      stage.start();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

so, I found a solution to this problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022085/doubleclick-studio-clicktag-after-using-swiffy/31172471?noredirect=1#comment52926332_31172471) 
And I'm also not sure if this is correct for a DCM file since I don't know if an exit URL can be defined without a clicktag

**[EDIT] The agency now tells me that they don't have the problem of two windows opening, but they got the error that no clicktag was found... and of course. So I don't know what to do here.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<script src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"> </script> 
     <style>
      #bg-exit {
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
     cursor: pointer;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     }
      </style> 
    <title>GOOGLE DCM</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v8.0/runtime.js"></script>
    <script>
      swiffyobject = { blablabla swiffy code};
    </script>
    <style>html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}</style>
  </head>

    <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
   <div id="bg-exit"> 
    <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 120px; height: 600px; border:1px solid black;  box-sizing: border-box; ">
    </div>
   </div> 

    <script>      
      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {});

      stage.start();
    </script>

   <script>
    window.onload = function() {
  if (Enabler.isInitialized()) {
    enablerInitHandler();
  } else {
    Enabler.addEventListener(studio.events.StudioEvent.INIT, enablerInitHandler);
  }
}

function enablerInitHandler() {

}
    function bgExitHandler(e) {
  Enabler.exit('Background Exit');
}

document.getElementById('bg-exit').addEventListener('click', bgExitHandler, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I really need to fix this as soon as possible, otherwise I'll have to redo 35 banners in GWD in just a few hours so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a bgExit event but no clicktag ?

var clickTag = "http://www.google.com"; 
        GOOGLE DCM